# AngularJS Failed to instantiate module, were dependency exists

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to create a set of modules, that will be used across multiple projects.

The 'wsLang' module is defined, with a provider and a filter.

When trying to use it in another module, I just can't seem to get access to 'wsTranslationProvider', and I don't know why!

I've copied the code to a single HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="test">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular App</title>
</head>
<body>

<div data-ng-controller="ctrl1 as vm">
    <p>{{vm.a | wsTranslate}}</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('wsLang', [])
        .provider('wsTranslationProvider', function() {
            this.locale = 'en';
            this.phrases = {};

            this.setLocale = function (locale) {
                if (locale.length < 2) return;
                this.locale = locale;
            };

            this.setPhrases = function (phrases, locale) {
                if (locale === undefined) locale = this.locale;
                this.phrases[locale] = phrases;
            };

            this.addPhrase = function (key, value, locale) {
                if (locale === undefined) locale = this.locale;
                this.phrases[locale][key] = value;
            };

            this.getPhrase = function (key, locale) {
                if (locale === undefined) locale = this.locale;
                if (this.phrases[locale] !== undefined) {
                    if (this.phrases[locale][key] !== undefined) {
                        return this.phrases[locale][key];
                    }
                }
                return key;
            };

            this.$get = function () {
                return this;
            };
        })
        .filter('wsTranslate', ['wsTranslationProvider', function(provider) {
            return function(input) {
                return provider.getPhrase(input);
            };
        }]);

angular.module('test', ['wsLang'])
        .config(function(wsTranslationProvider) {
            wsTranslationProvider.setLocale('en');
            wsTranslationProvider.addPhrase('test', 'Test');

        })
        .controller('ctrl1', function() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.a = 'test';
        });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

No matter what I try, the 'wsTranslationProvider' is not recognized in the other module. Keep getting the 'failed to instantiate module' error with 'unknown provider: wsTranslationProvider'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe something on this page would be of use: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your provider without the *Provider* suffix in the name:

```
angular.module('wsLang', [])
  .provider('wsTranslation', function() {
    ...
  });
```

For some reason (I want to investigate later) using a provider defined in other module requires this. If you change your provider to be defined in the same *test* module your code will work too.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working, now just saying "unknown provider: wsTranslation"...

Comment: Now it's really weird. The plunkr works fine. But when I'm adding to it the "addPhrase" function, I get the same error again...Totally confused here :/

Comment: To be more accurate, adding the function to the provider works, but calling it in the config of the 'test' module causes the error

Comment: Working...There was an error in the addPharse function that causes the error. Thank you

Comment: Yes, clearly you have an error in your code. this.phrases doesn't contain any entry. Good luck!